# Linking a .chm file to a .dll in Visual Studio 2010 C# Project

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, dll, chm

I have just got hold of the following binaries because
[I want a nice way to parse CSV files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F) in my Visual Studio 2010 C# project.

The binaries file includes a `.dll`, `.xml` and `.chm` file.

I linked the `.dll` into my project using the Add Reference option in the Project menu. Visual Studio recognises the class and it comes up as an option with IntelliSense, however, I cannot see the documentation in the `.xml` file within Visual Studio.

How do I see the documentation?

Comment: Well, you got a .chm file.  Open it.

Comment: Should this not appear in IntelliSense though? Or have I got this all wrong?

Comment: The CHM is a binary file compiled from HTML files and isn't going into the IntelliSense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the documentation please double-click on a PC having Windows installed (and this is the only way at this stage for you). But one step you have to do first:

When you unzip the CHM only the TOC is showing, the right information panel is blank (file not found). 
Microsoft is trying to protect you from CHM files (since they can execute stuff). Using the Windows built-in Zip support it makes sense that Windows security may try to stop you viewing the CHM from a ZIP.

After unzipping the CHM you need to right-click it, select properties and click the unblock button.